# Powershell 2.0 Function Help parameter checks

Tags: validation, powershell, parameters

Background:
This is a parameter validation, its being run on powershell 2.0
there is no option to upgrade the WMF. My problem is... 
if both parameters are empty, then display the Specify a parameter, if only P1 is empty display another if P2 is is empty then display another and if both are occupied, display another. I can't find a way to make it work right...
please help

```
Function checkParam
{
    write-verbose "Parameter Validation"
    If ("Lzu","Mlv","Irv" -Contains $MoveDBsTo)
        {$param1=1}
    else{$param1=0}

    If (1,2,3 -Contains $SelectedPref)
        {$param2=1}
    else{$param2=0}

    If ($param1 -and $param2 -eq 0)
        {
        $ErrorParams4 = @{
                     Message="SYNTAX ERROR: `n Specify a parameter"
                     Category="InvalidData"
                    }
        Write-error @ErrorParams4
        $paramsEmpty=1
        Exit
        }

    If ($param1 -eq 0 -and $param2 -ne 1)
        {
        $ErrorParams1 = @{
                         Message="SYNTAX ERROR: `n Check syntax: -MoveDBsto [Lzu, Mlv, Irv]"
                         Category="InvalidData"
                        }
        $param1=2
        Write-error @ErrorParams1
        Exit
        }

    If ($param2 -eq 0 -and $param1 -ne 1)
        {
        $ErrorParams2 = @{
                     Message="SYNTAX ERROR: `n Check syntax: -SelectedPref [1,2,3]" 
                     Category="InvalidData"
                    }
        $param2=2
        Write-error @ErrorParams2
        Exit
        }

    If ($param1 + $param2 -eq 2)
        {
        $ErrorParams3 = @{
                         Message="SYNTAX ERROR: `n Specify only one parameter" 
                         Category="InvalidData"
                        }
        Write-error @ErrorParams3
        Exit
        }
}

checkParam
```

Comment: You can use parameter validation on PowerShell v2. Run `help about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters` for details.

Comment: [CmdletBinding()]
Param
  (
    [validateset ("Lzu","Mlv","Irv", IgnoreCase= $true)]
  [String] $MoveDBsTo = $null, #$global:param1
    [validateset (1, 2, 3)]
 [Int] $SelectedPref = $null  #$global:param2
 )

Comment: Update your question with what you tried and tell specifically _how_ it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried  the parameter validation with the code posted above.

After setting the "set validation" and running with no parameters it should throw an error message requesting a param.
I tought about using mandatory, however there are 2 params and it should only run with 1 parameter, so using mandatory for both params wouln't work, same goes for "not null".

The way I want this to work is that 1 out of 2 parameters needs to be specified and validated.

I can't think of a way to make this work using the default parameter validation, which is why I created the custom function.

Comment: You can probably do what you need by creating parameter sets. It's explained in the documentation.